# Github project import into my own project

Tags: android, android-studio

Here it goes.. I am a bloody beginner in programming! So i am also new to android studio..

Here is what i've got: 
I am playing around with those fragments and the navigation drawer, everything works just fine, but is it possible to import, lets call it a "whole" github project as fragment class ? Just copy and paste gave me too many errors for me to understand..

(A bit more detailed, i want to build a calendar app, and the android studio calendarview gives me no access to customize the view, so i wanted to use [CompactCalenderView](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView) just for some testing..

Greetings PatPat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your app's build.gradle's dependency block

`compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.7.9'`

**EDIT:**

From Gudin's comment:

On the left side in your android studio open the "Project" tab, if its already open then you should see a file/folder structure on the left side, in the same tab there is a drop down which when you open there should be an option called `android` just click on it, Now you will be able to see a folder called `Gradle scripts`, expand it and open the `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Comment: Just some clarification, since he is begginer: In AndroidStudio, on the left side there is Project View, and you will find GradleScripts folder. Inside there are two gradle.build files. One that you are looking for has (Module: app) next to it.

Double click that file, and paste line of code in answer above inside dependencies { ... } and sync your project.

Comment: @Gudin you forgot to mention to switch to the android view in order to view  the gradle scripts in the way you mention in the comment

Comment: Yea, I omitted that, because Android view is default setting, so I hoped he didn't change it.

Comment: never expected that fast response,thanks! Need some time for testing.. i nearly cleared out all errors, but i think this is maybe a bit too high for me...

i got troubles now with the fragment class.. i wanted to copy paste the github main activity class as a fragment class in my project, the problems i got now are: the programmer is using in his class actionbar stuff, so i have to extend the class with AppCompatActivity .. but its already extended by Fragments.. and whats the difference between the onCreate() und onCreateView() .. i think i've reached my limits for this time.. :)

Comment: thats not how library projects are intended for use, you are not supposed to copy the files individually and add it to your project ! thats what gradle is for, like i mentioned in the answer all you need to do is specify dependency on that project as mentioned in the answer, then you will be able to use the classes, and its functions of the library

Comment: oh .. god, now my brain got it.. by adding the compile line, i get access to the whole library of the project, and can use his stuff, gnah! thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

[image: ScreenShot of bulild.gradle file]

First get take a good look the image ive provided
can you see that there are 2 build.gradle files? Saw that ??Good..

Now select that Gradle build with module:app file

Next put the dependencies in the dependency section just as i have done sync or rebuild the project and that pretty much it ..Hope this helps